# Change behaviour of mapping in certain cases, and reuse functionality in all others

Tags: vim

I'm trying to change the behavior of "K" in certain circumstances, but keep its original functionality in all the others. Here's my failed attempt

```
function! GetDocumentation()
    if &filetype == 'java'
        JavaDocSearch
    else
        normal K
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap K :call GetDocumentation()<CR>
```

However since I use K in a function, when it's called as result of the remapping, the new mapping of K is used, and I get infinite recursion. I guess I could somehow fit the gist of the function onto the `nnoremap` line, but it seems awkward, and it would be nice to forcefully use the original mapping of a key.

Hope this makes sense,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:normal` command without the `!` modifier—as it is used in the
function—executes its arguments as Normal mode commands *taking mappings into
consideration*.  This is why the line

```
        normal K
```

runs the mapping that has overridden the default handler.  So, to ignore
mappings shadowing commands, change the line as follows,

```
        normal! K
```

Answer (score 2):

@ib. is right: you should be using `:normal!` here. But function is an overkill: the following expression mapping is sufficient:

```
nnoremap <expr> K ((&filetype is# "java")?(":JavaDocSearch\n"):("K"))
```

This mapping won’t trigger itself due to `nore` and also is eight lines shorter.

Comment: Too many unnecessary parentheses are spoiling the beauty of the expression.  In this case all of them could be seamlessly removed: `:nnoremap <expr> K &ft is# 'java' ? ":JavaDocSearch\n" : 'K'`.

Comment: @ib. These parenthesis allow me to write programs in different languages without remembering what is the operator precedence difference between them. Main idea is “having additional parenthesis cannot hurt, but not having it can”.